# UINavigationBar. Apperance. setBarTintColor doesn't work

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uicolor, uiappearance

When I call

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

in

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

All works fine, but the following code gives white color:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:21.0 green:194.0 blue:179.0 alpha:0.5]];
```

I can't understand why. NavBar translucent is enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:21.0 green:194.0 blue:179.0 alpha:0.5]
```

You're creating your `UIColor` wrong - for each parameter needed to create a `UIColor`, a value between **`0.0`** and **`1.0`** is accepted. To get these, you divide your RGB values by 255:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:21.0/255.0 green:194.0/255.0 blue:179.0/255.0 alpha:0.5]
```

Comment: Don't encourage duplicates.